# Javascript checkbox logic error

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a code that will select the check box and display the text of selected checkbox without appending(time being).Java Script is not working... What is the error?

```
<input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
<label id="checktext"></label>
```

The Javascript is :

```
checktext.innerText = gettext("Checkbox1", "Checkbox2");
function gettext(a, b) {
   var x = document.getElementById(a);
   var y = document.getElementById(b);
   if (x.checked)
     return x.textContent;
   else if (y.checked)
     return y.textContent;
}
```

Comment: Where is the textContent for <input> tags?
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1">TestContent</input>

Comment: Even if I give a text content (text between <input> </input>.. it doesn't work)..

Comment: use innerText everywhere and give a try

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/37LM9/).

I don't exactly understand what your problem is (since you haven't really explained it), but I think you should use the `value` attribute for checkboxes.

```
function gettext(a, b) {
   var x = document.getElementById(a);
   var y = document.getElementById(b);
   if (x.checked)
       return x.value;
   else if (y.checked)
       return y.value;
}
```